# Count registers by day including zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in a SQL Server database containing a register of each time a user downloads an image from my app so my table `TBL_Downloads` has the following structure:

```
UserID|  ImageID  | DownloadDate              |
------+-----------+---------------------------+
  292 |    782    |  02-01-2016 14:20:22.737  |
  292 |    783    |  02-01-2016 14:20:22.737  |
  292 |    784    |  02-02-2016 14:20:22.737  |
  292 |    785    |  02-04-2016 14:20:22.737  |
  292 |    786    |  02-05-2016 14:20:22.737  |
  292 |    787    |  02-06-2016 14:20:22.737  |
```

In table there are shown only registers for 1 specific user even when there are several just to simplify the example.

What I would like to have is a result table containing the number of downloads made BY DAY in the last 30 days for a specific user including a zero for the days in which there was no download. I currently have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Downloads
FROM TBL_Downloads
WHERE DownloadDate BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
  AND IdUser = 292
GROUP BY CAST(DownloadDate AS DATE)
```

This returns a table with the sum, but only for days for which there is at least one entry of a download.

Do you have any idea how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Calendar or dates table for this sort of thing.

For only 152kb in memory, you can have 30 years of dates in a table with this:

```
/* dates table */
declare @fromdate date = '20000101';
declare @years    int  = 30;
/* 30 years, 19 used data pages ~152kb in memory, ~264kb on disk */
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
select top (datediff(day, @fromdate,dateadd(year,@years,@fromdate)))
    [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
into dbo.Dates
from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo
               cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
order by [Date];
create unique clustered index ix_dbo_Dates_date
  on dbo.Dates([Date]);
```

Without taking the actual step of creating a table, you can use it inside a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with just this:

```
declare @fromdate date = dateadd(day  , datediff(day  , 0, getdate() )-30 , 0); 
declare @thrudate date = dateadd(day  , datediff(day  , 0, getdate() ), 0);
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (datediff(day, @fromdate, @thrudate)+1) 
      [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo
                cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
   order by [Date]
)
select [Date]
from dates;
```

---

Use either like so:

```
select 
    d.Date
  , count(t.DownloadDate) as DownloadCount
from dates d
  left join TBL_Downloads t
    on d.date = convert(date,t.DownloadDate)
   and t.userid = 292
where d.date >= dateadd(day  , datediff(day  , 0, getdate() )-30 , 0)
  and d.date <= dateadd(day  , datediff(day  , 0, getdate() ), 0)
group by d.date
```

rextester **demo**: http://rextester.com/ISK37732 (dates changed to be within last 30 days)

returns:

```
+------------+---------------+
|    Date    | DownloadCount |
+------------+---------------+
| 2017-02-27 |             0 |
| 2017-02-28 |             0 |
| 2017-03-01 |             2 |
| 2017-03-02 |             1 |
| 2017-03-03 |             0 |
| 2017-03-04 |             1 |
| 2017-03-05 |             1 |
| 2017-03-06 |             1 |
| 2017-03-07 |             0 |
| 2017-03-08 |             0 |
| 2017-03-09 |             0 |
| 2017-03-10 |             0 |
| 2017-03-11 |             0 |
| 2017-03-12 |             0 |
| 2017-03-13 |             0 |
| 2017-03-14 |             0 |
| 2017-03-15 |             0 |
| 2017-03-16 |             0 |
| 2017-03-17 |             0 |
| 2017-03-18 |             0 |
| 2017-03-19 |             0 |
| 2017-03-20 |             0 |
| 2017-03-21 |             0 |
| 2017-03-22 |             0 |
| 2017-03-23 |             0 |
| 2017-03-24 |             0 |
| 2017-03-25 |             0 |
| 2017-03-26 |             0 |
| 2017-03-27 |             0 |
| 2017-03-28 |             0 |
| 2017-03-29 |             0 |
+------------+---------------+
```

---

Number and Calendar table reference:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 2 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 3 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)
- [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-sql/62867/)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in sql Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in sql Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)
- [tsql Function to Determine Holidays in sql Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1537/tsql-function-to-determine-holidays-in-sql-server/)
- [F_table_date - Michael Valentine Jones](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=61519)

Comment: The solution is great but it is not considering the TBL_Downloads table has registers from different users, once I add the `WHERE userid=292` the rows in cero disappear again. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: @AlejandroFlores put `and userid=292` in the `left join` condition instead of a `where` -- updated my answer and the rextester demo to show what I mean.

Comment: I have used that same clause before. I don't know why I din't came up with it. It worked perfectly. I'm a little bit new on this, so thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by to find count and generate dates using Common Table Expressions

```
--Final Query - For this query to execute you require #dates to be populated as below
select cte_start_date as [date], coalesce(cnt,0) as DownLoadCount from #dates d left join
(
    select userid,convert(date,DownloadDate) dt , count( convert(date,DownloadDate)) as cnt from #yourDownloads
    group by userid, convert(date,DownloadDate)
) a
on d.cte_start_date = a.dt
```

Common Table Expression recursive query to populate date for that month

```
--Populuating dates
declare @start_date date = '02-01-2016'
declare @end_date date = eomonth('02-01-2016')
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT @start_date AS cte_start_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, cte_start_date)
    FROM CTE
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, cte_start_date) <= @end_date    
)
select * into #dates from cte
```

Your Input table

```
create table #yourDownloads (UserId int, ImageId int, DownloadDate datetime)

insert into #yourDownloads 
( UserID ,  ImageID , DownloadDate  ) values
 (  292 ,  782   ,'02-01-2016 14:20:22.737')
,(  292 ,  783   ,'02-01-2016 14:20:22.737')
,(  292 ,  784   ,'02-02-2016 14:20:22.737')
,(  292 ,  785   ,'02-04-2016 14:20:22.737')
,(  292 ,  786   ,'02-05-2016 14:20:22.737')
,(  292 ,  787   ,'02-06-2016 14:20:22.737')
```

Comment: You might want to check out the performance of the recursive cte compared to some other options. It gets pretty bad as you need to generate more values.[Generate a set or sequence without loops - 2 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)